# XML parsing:unexpected end of input, during execution of T-SQL job step

Tags: sql-server, sql-job

I have a piece of code that need to run as a recurrent SQL job.

When running the code as simple query inside the SQL Server query editor
it runs successfully and return the expected results (merging several lines from the XML into an existing table).

But when creating a new job for SQL Server Agent, adding a single step that need to run the exact same script, it always fails when trying to execute

```
INSERT #xml ( [XMLData] )
```

Error message is:

> Executing as user 'myUser': XML Parsing: line 19 column 0, unexpected end
>   of input.

If the XML was invalid in any way then this error message would appear when executing the same line in it's script version. It must be something else.

Comment: It's a file that I read from a remote domain into my database server. Is that  answering your question?

Comment: Can you post the content of the file and a screenshot of your SSIS package?

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I'm allowed to publish the XML here. Have to ask permission from my boss. Will have to wait for tomorrow. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue when Google Geocoding and parsing the XML result. It seems that when run via an SQL job, the XML result is being truncated. I found the solution [here](http://www.progtown.com/topic376715-a-problem-with-spoagetproperty-p2.html).

You have to put the following at the start of your stored procedure:

```
SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647;
```